# How do I choose an SSD drive that does not require TRIM support?

Tags: ssd, osx-yosemite, trim

Apple has decided to implement kext-signing in core services on startup (as of Yosemite and for the unknown future?). This creates issues for SSDs that require TRIM support for optimal function and longevity. Whether this is vendor lock in or not, it's made TRIM enabled DIY SSD upgrades a security concern. If you bought a SSD that needs TRIM support, there are many reported issues when performing NVRAM/PRAM reset and potential future system update conflicts in addition to the current security tradeoffs (see below). Trim Enabler author says using Trim Enabler by turning off kext signing is cracking a walnut with a sledgehammer.

How should I discern SSD upgrade options that don't require TRIM? Given a set of SSDs, how do I choose the best option for speed and longevity?

If you've purchased a non TRIM drive (e.g. Sandforce) that's working well, please offer an explanation of which features you used as basis for selection and if/how you're managing TRIM.

Comment: SSDs don't *require* TRIM. It just helps with wear leveling.

Answer (score 1):

As of Yosemite 10.10.4 OS X natively supports TRIM on third party SSDs. All can enable TRIM with superuser permissions in Terminal (requires reboot) with the following command:

> sudo trimforce enable

Then press Y. 
After system reboots you can confirm by checking System-menu()>"About This Mac">"System Report"
Under Hardware select SATA/SATA Express and select the SSD
Bellow it look for "TRIM Support" and if it says Yes It worked.

Comment: Be aware the Apple-icon in your answer doesn't show on non-Mac systems. Consider changing this to "System-menu"->"About this Mac".